# Learning C# and undertand this error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#

How to fix my problem with double Value?
I use Convert.ToInt16 to convert

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace Taxi_fare
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the distance of journey in Kilometers");
        int distance = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        int distanceprice = distance * 1.50;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of passengers");
        int passenger = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int passengerprice = passenger * 2;
        int finalprice = passengerprice + distanceprice;
        Console.WriteLine(finalprice);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add your code inline.

Comment: What's the question? Have you tried searching the internet for that error? What exactly is holding you up?

Comment: Don't post links to images of code.  Instead you should copy and paste the code into the question.  Also the error is because a cast from `double` to `int` can result in the loss of information and thus should be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

distance variable is of type integer. "1.50" number, although not stored in a variable but used directly in that statement, is of type double. You can check this fact by executing these 2 lines of code

```
    var num = 1.50;
    Console.WriteLine(num.GetType().FullName); // Prints "System.Double" to console
```

You can use https://dotnetfiddle.net/ to quickly execute C# code snippets.

When multiplying a number of type integer by a number of type double, the result is a number of type double. Therefore, distanceprice variable should have been declared as type double, to be able to store the result.

```
    int num = 3;
    double res = num * 1.5;

    Console.WriteLine(res); // prints 4.5 
    Console.WriteLine(res.GetType().FullName); // prints System.Double
```

If you try to multiply 3 (int) by 1.5 (double), the result is 4.5 (double). Integer variables cannot store decimal places. Therefore, an integer variable can only store the number 4 instead of 4.5. For this reason, an implicit conversion cannot be done from double to int, because it results in a data loss. You have to manage these situations yourself. That's literally what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Double and int are two different variable.
Int is whole numbers and double are decimals numbers (16 decimals max).
You need to convert your int into a double to use it in what you’re doing.
Try puting (double) before it.
double myDouble = (double)myInt;

Edit: didn’t see your code. If you multiply by 1.5 (without f) it’ll be a double. You need to do (int)(distance * 1.50f).

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to use this link, but here is how you can convert doubles into integers:

```
int a;
double b = 1;
b = Convert.ToInt32(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the double type for calculations, corrected your code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the distance of journey in Kilometers");
        double distance = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double distanceprice = distance * 1.50;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of passengers");
        double passenger = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double passengerprice = passenger * 2;
        double finalprice = passengerprice + distanceprice;
        Console.WriteLine(finalprice);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store this in the variable (this is a double value). It can't automatically convert this to int.You can fix it by converting like that:
 int.Parse(distance * 1.5);

or store the value as double.